# Liferay 7.0 Portlets Don't Deploy Properly After Restart

Tags: portlet, liferay-7, spring-portlet-mvc

I have a number of portlets that work fine after a hot deploy, but do not work after restarting Liferay (auto-deploy). The only way I can get them to work again is by rebuilding and doing another hot deploy.

I have 3 different spring-mvc portlets (org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet). The simplest of the 3 has no issues on restart, while the other 2 do not work. All three created from the base project generated using Eclipse-LiferayIDE -> new spring-mvc-portlet liferay module.

Their web.xml, portlet.xml, liferay-portlet.xml, liferay-plugin-package.properties, portlet-application-context.xml and spring/application-context.xml, PortletViewController.java, files are all identical, aside from name changes.

My best guess is that it's some sort of class loading issue.

I've compared the dependencies of all 3.

```
                                                Working                           Fail1                                      Fail2
Dependency                                      Version       Scope    Exclusions Version       Scope    Exclusions          Version       Scope    Exclusions
org.springframework.spring-webmvc-portlet       4.1.9.RELEASE compile  --         4.1.9.RELEASE compile  --                  4.1.9.RELEASE compile  --
com.liferay.portal.com.liferay.portal.kernel    2.46.1        provided --         2.46.1        provided --                  2.46.1        provided --
javax.portlet.portlet-api                       3.0.0         provided --         3.0.0         provided --                  3.0.0         provided --
javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api                 3.1.0         provided --         3.1.0         provided --                  3.1.0         provided --
org.osgi.org.osgi.service.component.annotations 1.3.0         provided --         1.3.0         provided --                  1.3.0         provided --
org.slf4j.slf4j-log4j12                         1.7.22        provided --         1.7.22        provided --                  1.7.22        provided --
commons-lang.commons-lang                       --            --       --         2.6           compile  --                  --            --       --
com.liferay.portal.com.liferay.util.taglib      --            --       --         2.8.0         compile  --                  2.8.0         compile  --
javax.servlet.javax.servlet.jsp-api             --            --       --         2.3.1         provided --                  2.3.1         provided --
oracle.ojdbc6                                   --            --       --         11.2.0.3      provided --                  11.2.0.3      provided --
org.glassfish.web.jstl-impl                     --            --       --         1.2           provided jsp-api,servlet-api 1.2           provided jsp-api,servlet-api
org.hibernate.hibernate-core                    --            --       --         4.1.3.Final   compile  --                  --            --       --
org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl         --            --       --         --                                         1.9.13        compile  --
```

I suspect the problem to be with one of the overlapping dependencies between the 2 failing portlets.

```
com.liferay.portal.com.liferay.util.taglib
javax.servlet.javax.servlet.jsp-api
oracle.ojdbc6
org.glassfish.web.jstl-impl
```

Any idea if these dependencies would be causing an issue?

Here's the stack trace for the error generated. There are no errors during the initial auto-deploy, only after I navigate to a page where the portlet is used.

```
15:15:29,583 ERROR [ajp-nio-8009-exec-6][DispatcherPortlet:573] Could not complete request
org.springframework.web.portlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler found for portlet request: mode 'view', phase 'RENDER_PHASE', parameters map[[empty]]
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.noHandlerFound(DispatcherPortlet.java:1031)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doRenderService(DispatcherPortlet.java:730)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:536)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.doDispatch(FrameworkPortlet.java:483)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:262)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
    at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ServletExceptionAdapter.service(ServletExceptionAdapter.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:99)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.FilterExceptionAdapter.doFilter(FilterExceptionAdapter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:531)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:606)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:392)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.render(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1584)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor671.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:286)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:283)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    .....
```

I've cut the trace short to fit the character limit.

---

Liferay Installation: Liferay 7 Tomcat Bundle (liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga5)

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, the issue seems to have been resolved by completely removing these dependencies:

```
com.liferay.portal.com.liferay.util.taglib
org.glassfish.web.jstl-impl
```

I have been porting these portlets from Liferay 6.0.6, starting with no additional dependencies and adding them one by one as needed, so at some point something lead me to believe I needed them. Hopefully I don't.